# Auto connect bluetooth

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I occasionally use my computer as speakers for my iPad via bluetooth.  If I want to do this I must go to the right click the bluetooth icon in the tray, click show devices, click on the iPad, and finally click connect.

Is there any way to automatically connect my iPad whenever it is in range?  Or if not, is there command line tool, or some way to script the connection to get it setup faster?

[image: bluetooth connect dialog]

Comment: Hmm, I thought BT peripherals would connect automatically once in range & if paired - at least that's been the case with my A2DP headset.

Comment: That is what I thought as well, but I have found posts on the Internet that confirm this behavior.  I was hoping someone had a good idea for a work-around.  This only seems to happen when you are streaming audio to windows, and not the other way around.

Comment: +1. I *would like to* use my bluetooth headset with my PC but I rarely can get it to reconnect. I typically have to remove and re-add it each time. It's quite bothersome.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way that I have found for Bluetooth services to auto-connect. However, there exists (3) 3rd party solutions.

free. mixed results, some commands did not work with my adapter:
[Bluetooth Command Line Tools](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/)

Potentially free (depending on hardware). Comes with 30 day trial, works well:
[Toshiba Bluetooth Stack](http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=3461138)

non-free. Have not tried, but heard positive things:
[BlueSoleil](http://www.bluesoleil.com/index.aspx)